# Missing libmmal.so with picamera library

Tags: python

After installing the picamera library using pip, whenever I import the library I get this error:

```
OSError: libmmal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am running ubuntu 14.04, with python 2.7.6.

When I attemt to search for this elusive libmmal.so:

```
$ sudo find / -name libmmal.so
/root/mounts/backups/root/opt/vc/lib/libmmal.so
/root/mounts/root-backup/opt/vc/lib/libmmal.so
```

Both of which are backups of my raspberry pi, and are therefore irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

On a raspberry, the libmmal.so library should be located at `/opt/vc/lib`, did you by any chance wipe this folder?

The firmware located in that directory is updated via

> sudo rpi-update

If this tells you that you are already at the newest version, you can force an update by prior running

> sudo rm /boot/.firmware_version

Please also see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32947446/875020).

Are you running ubuntu 14.04 on your rpi? If not, i think you will have to recompile the libraries from the [firmware](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/hardfp/opt/vc/lib).

Comment: I follow steps, nothing worked, just firmware update, but sill same issue

Comment: @TejasTank i think then its time to create your own question with detailed information on your setup and maybe link to this one for reference.

Comment: I face same issue as questation mention, I do follow and it did not worked. In additional, I found with raspberry latest version 64 bit, this face and official says depricated this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Raspbian based on Debian Bullseye, so if you install the Raspbian Lagacy and activate the camera everything should work properly. But if you want to use Rasbian based on Debian Bullseye then proceed the following steps:

- Make sure that the camera is properly connected to the camera port with flat cable and `Legacy camera` is activated under `raspi-config -> interfaces`
- Update:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```
- Check if the path for `libmmal.so` exists under `/opt/vc/lib` or  `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/`:

  ```
  sudo ldconfig -p | grep mmal
  ```
- If not, update Raspberry Pi firmware and reboot:

  ```
  sudo rpi-update
  sudo reboot
  ```
- Check if there exists `video0` under `/dev`: `ls /dev/`, then it should works.
- If not, it is recommended to increase the GPU memory (under `Performance Options -> GPU Memory`) to >=128MB and then add the following to the `/boot/config.txt`:

  ```
  start_x=1
  ```
- Read/enable the raspberry pi camera module:

  ```
  modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
  ```
- To load the module automatically add `bcm2835-v4l2` to `/etc/modules`.
- Reboot and then `video0` should be appeared under `/dev`.
- Test the camera:

  ```py
  from picamera import PiCamera
  from time import sleep

  camera = PiCamera()

  camera.start_preview()
  sleep(5)
  camera.stop_preview()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 64-bit raspbian OS, it's not going to work.