# Can I use picamera with this version of Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I used to use the [picamera Python module](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/), along with a [Raspberry Pi Camera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/camera-module-setup/) on Raspbian OS on my Raspberry Pi Model B.

Now I am running [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi). However, I cannot use picamera anymore because I cannot enable the Raspberry Pi Camera. I cannot enable the Raspberry Pi Camera because I do not have Raspberry Pi firmware, so to speak. I actually have Ubuntu-rpi2 firmware.

Here's the output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux ubuntu 3.18.0-20-rpi2 #21-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Sun Apr 5 01:56:02 UTC 2014 armv71 armv71 armv71 GNU/Linux
```

Is it even possible to run Ubuntu and have the necessary RPi firmware to use the RPi Camera at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

According to a post [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=100553) `by fo0bar » Fri Feb 27, 2015 3:49 am` the [userland firmware](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland) comes prebuilt via a PPA, the availability of the firmware is also stated at [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi). I dont have an rpi2 with ubuntu, but i would assume the PPA is already in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. If not, see the [ppa description](https://launchpad.net/~fo0bar/+archive/ubuntu/rpi2) on how to add it.

Then, try

> sudo apt-get install libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev

and be sure to enable the camera from

> raspi-config