# Raspberry Cam stop working after running 2 days

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi

I have written a program to capture and save images using **RPi Cam**.
The system works well, but suddenly I get the following errors:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port 
vc.ril.image_encode:out:0(JPEG): ENOMEM
mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable port 
vc.ril.image_encode:out:0(JPEG)
(0xc8a100) (ENOMEM)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Test_cam.py", line 300, in <module>
    putfunc()
  File "./Test_cam.py", line 169, in putfunc
    oneshot(_client_id)
  File "./Test_cam.py", line 137, in oneshot
    _cam.capture(ifn, use_video_port=True,resize=(1920,1080),splitter_port=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1418, in capture
    encoder.start(output)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 1126, in start
    super(PiCookedOneImageEncoder, self).start(output)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 377, in start
    self.output_port.enable(self._callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 1249, in enable
    prefix="Unable to enable port %s" % self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    **raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)**
**picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Unable to enable port vc.ril.image_encode:out:0: Out of memory**
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to format your error log.

Comment: Thank you sir!  I just open the PiCamera without closing! :)

Comment: not something silly like your SD card is full with all the images you captured?

Comment: Here is my code, problem still exist. I delete captured image and video after 10mins, The SD card is never full

Comment: @stovfl my code as following

Comment: My I see the output of `print( ifn )`. Why do you have different `splitter_port=0` and​ `splitter_port=1`? Which is the right one?

Comment: I want to save both image and video at the same time, image uses splitter_port = 0, video use splitter_port = 1;

Comment: ifn give filename.jpg

Comment: @stovfl I dont know what does "memory" mean in "out of memory" term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Related:**
>   Error Message "_mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port_" is from **libmmal.so**.
>
> > Found the following in [API - mmalobj](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/blob/master/docs/api_mmalobj.rst)
> >     **Warning**
> >     This part of the API is still experimental and subject to change in future versions.

Verify, that you are using the **latest** `picamera module` and `libmmal.so`. As `picamera` uses `libmmal.so`, verfiy also you are using compatible Versions.

Further Information sites:
[raspberrypi.org: Pure Python camera interface](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=56478&start=450) the Maintainer of `picamera`
[SO Answer: HowTo update libmmal.so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32930117/7414759)

---

> **Comment**: I dont know what does "memory" mean in "out of memory" term

Could be a follow up error.

> **Error Message**:
>   mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port
>   vc.ril.image_encode:out:0(JPEG): ENOMEM

There must be something wrong with the **port**.
Could also a **Buffer overrun** as a result of long time running.

---

To **verify** your *camera* is not damaged, try the following script:

```
from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
camera.start_preview()
# Camera warm-up time
sleep(2)
camera.capture('foo.jpg', resize=(320, 240))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (time.time() - start) < vterm:
    _cam.annotate_text = id + "\n" + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    nt = time.time()
    if (nt - pt) > iterm:
        ifn = tmpfname('jpg') 
        _cam.capture(ifn, use_video_port=True,resize=(1920,1080),splitter_port=0)
        tmp2nofile(nt, _path['live'], ifn, 'jpg')
        pt = nt
        if _debug:
            print 'image',ifn
    time.sleep(0.1)
_cam.stop_recording(splitter_port=1)
tmp2nofile(start, _path['live'], vfn, 'h264')
_cam.stop_preview()
_cam.close()
```